# OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)"

Tags: sql-server-2008

**ERROR MSG:** The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" does not support the required transaction interface.
I am stucked finding solutions for this error (see **ERROR MSG**).
Here is part of my code:

```
.....
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;
        Database=C:\Folder\file_output.xls',
        'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
        SELECT FROM FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 dbo.MY_TABLE 
        WHERE TRANS_ID = 1 
        ORDER BY CTRL_NO ASC
.....
```

The above code is contained inside an SP... This is the last SP that is run in a series of SP calls.
Here is the chain/flow of execution: SP1->SP2->SP3->SP4 (assuming SP4 contains the above code)
But an error occurs as what the **ERROR MSG** suggests during the entire execution flow.
Here are the 2 scenarios that I've tried to test/trace the error.
- Run the the chain of SPs ----> result: error occurs
- Comment/Remove SP4, then run SP1->SP2->SP3 only. Then separately execute SP4. ----> result: okay
PLS. NOTE:I need to execute the SPs in flow.
          There is no web/any front-end except SP1 is executed through SQL runner
I now wonder if this is a bug in MS SQL Server 2008 or I'm missing something.
If my question is still vague, kindly ask me for clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check "Non transacted updates" option in "Server objects - Linked servers - Providers -  Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" properties. Maybe you will need to restart your sql server.